# How to call a data member of the base class if it is being overwritten as a property in the derived class?

Tags: python, inheritance, overloading, descriptor

This question is similar to [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021464/python-how-to-call-a-property-of-the-base-class-if-this-property-is-being-overwr), with the difference that the data member in the base class is *not* wrapped by the descriptor protocol.

In other words, how can I access a member of the base class if I am overriding its name with a property in the derived class?

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = 5

class Derived(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        Base.__init__(self)

    @property
    def foo(self):
        return 1 + self.foo # doesn't work of course!

    @foo.setter
    def foo(self, f):
        self._foo = f

bar = Base()
print bar.foo

foobar = Derived()
print foobar.foo
```

Please note that I also need to define a setter because otherwise the assignment of self.foo in the base class doesn't work.

All in all the descriptor protocol doesn't seem to interact well with inheritance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Defining

```
def __init__(self):
    self.foo = 5
```

in `Base` makes `foo` a member (attribute) of the *instance*, not of the class. The *class* `Base` has no knowledge of `foo`, so there is no way to access it by something like a `super()` call.

This is not necessary, however. When you instanciate

```
foobar = Derived()
```

and the `__init__()` method of the base class calls

```
self.foo = 5
```

this will not result in the creation / overwriting of the attribute, but instead in `Derived`'s setter being called, meaning

```
self.foo.fset(5)
```

and thus `self._foo = 5`. So if you put

```
return 1 + self._foo
```

in your getter, you pretty much get what you want. If you need the value that `self.foo` is set to in `Base`'s constructor, just look at `_foo`, which was set correctly by the `@foo.setter`.

Comment: All of the answers are very interesting and I upvoted most of them but this one was straight to the point, it really made understand me the problem at hand.

Answer (score 9):

Life is simpler if you use delegation instead of inheritance.  This is Python.  You aren't obligated to inherit from `Base`.

```
class LooksLikeDerived( object ):
    def __init__( self ):
        self.base= Base()

    @property
    def foo(self):
        return 1 + self.base.foo # always works

    @foo.setter
    def foo(self, f):
        self.base.foo = f
```

But what about other methods of Base?  You duplicate the names in `LooksLikeDerived` and simply.

```
def someMethodOfBase( self, *args, **kw ):
    return self.base.someMethodOfBase( *args **kw )
```

Yes, it doesn't feel "DRY".  However, it prevents a lot of problems when "wrapping" some class in new functionality like you're trying to do.

Comment: Yeah, I'm indeed looking for more "pythonic" ways to organize my code, and I have been questioning my inheritance-based approach for a while. Your alternative, though, is not that convincing in my case, as I have a several levels deep inheritance chain, where each level defines new features. Having to redefine all the methods at each level would be definitely unfeasible. But I see your point.

Comment: @UncleZeiv: This is not an EITHER-OR situation.  You have many, many design patterns, including Strategy, Composition, Delegation and Inheritance.  Focus on Inheritance is a bad thing.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Foo(object):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kw):
        return object.__new__(cls, *args, **kw)

    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = 5

class Bar(Foo):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kw):
        self = object.__new__(cls, *args, **kw)
        self.__foo = Foo.__new__(Foo)
        return self

    def __init__(self):
        Foo.__init__(self)

    @property
    def foo(self):
        return 1 + self.__foo.foo

    @foo.setter
    def foo(self, foo):
        self.__foo.foo = foo

bar = Bar()
bar.foo = 10
print bar.foo
```

Answer (score 0):

once you have property with same name 'foo' it overrides the behaviour of access of name 'foo'
only way out seems that you explicitly set 'foo' in **dict**

btw: I use python 2.5 hence had to change code a bit

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = 5

class Derived(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        Base.__init__(self)

    def g_foo(self):
        return 1 + self.__dict__['foo'] # works now!

    def s_foo(self, f):
        self.__dict__['foo'] = f
        self._foo = f

    foo = property(g_foo, s_foo)

bar = Base()
print bar.foo

foobar = Derived()
print foobar.foo
```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, the thing to look at here is that you're trying to twist your code around a design that is simply poor. The property descriptors handle the request for a 'foo' attribute, and you want to bypass these completely, which is just wrong. You're already causing Base.**init** to assign foobar._foo = 5, so thats exactly where the getter needs to look, too.

class Base(object):
    def **init**(self):
        self.foo = 5

```
class Derived(Base):
  def __init__(self):
    Base.__init__(self)

  @property
  def foo(self):
    return 1 + self._foo # DOES work of course!

  @foo.setter
  def foo(self, f):
    self._foo = f

bar = Base()
print bar.foo

foobar = Derived()
print foobar.foo
```