# Python super and setting parent class property

Tags: python, super

I'm having a really strange problem with Python super() and inheritance and properties.  First, the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import pyglet
import pygame

class Sprite(pyglet.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, self.width, self.height)
        self.rect.center = self.x, self.y

    @property
    def x(self):
        return super().x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        super(Sprite, self.__class__).x.fset(self, value)
        self.rect.centerx = value

    @property
    def y(self):
        return super().y

    @y.setter
    def y(self, value):
        super(Sprite, self.__class__).y.fset(self, value)
        self.rect.centery = value
```

This works fine.  However, what I want (what seems Pythonic to me)

```
#super(Sprite, self.__class__).x.fset(self, value)
super().x = value
```

doesn't work even though

```
super().x
```

gets the value fine.  x in this case is a property of the superclass with both fset and fget defined.  So why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I was trying to find the correct language to back up why this behavior is the way it is, so as not to give you a "because it just is" answer... But it seems this question has been asked more than once, and that it boils down to the behavior of `super()`. You can see a 2010 discussion about this exact behavior here:  http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2010-April/099672.html

Ultimately, it really does just come down to super() calls only letting you access getters directly, and not setters. Setters must be accessed via `fset()` or `__set__()`. It is probably easiest explained as "super() functionality just doesn't support it". It will resolve the property functionality of a "get" operation, not the setter in a left handed assignment, in the "set" operation (hence the `fset()` method call). As you can see from the date of this discussion thread, its obviously been this way since the introduction of `super()`.

Maybe someone else has a more specifically technical reason, but frankly I'm not sure it even matters. If its not supported, thats pretty much a good enough reason.

Comment: I've filed a bug: http://bugs.python.org/issue14965  Hopefully this is resolved soon so this question is no longer relevant.

Comment: "its not supported ... a good enough reason" sounds like "because it just is".

Comment: @simonzack - I did say I was *trying* not to give that kind of answer and explain the most I possibly could about its functionality.

Comment: One more reason to avoid `super`

Comment: Can you provide an example that would be used in the child class?

Comment: @nmz787 what kind of example do you want? my answer wasn't about teaching how to use super(). it was just about why super behaves the way it does. The original question has the example of using fset

Comment: oh, I didn't see the OP say "This works fine. However", thanks!

Comment: This answer might be helpful if it actually showed how to access super using fset or __set__

Comment: @ErikAronesty: the OP already did: `super(self.__class__, self.__class__).x.fset(self, value)`

Comment: @MestreLion: `super(self.__class__, self.__class__)` is fundamentally broken, never do it (it seems like it works until you have another subclass, and get infinite recursion errors). In Python 3, `super(__class__, self.__class__)` is okay (`__class__` is provided to assist in implementing no-arg `super` via a faked closure scope), in Py 2, you'd just do `super(Sprite, self.__class__)` (where `Sprite` is whatever class the method is being defined in).

Answer (score 1):

`super(type(self), type(self)).setter.fset(self, value)` is a common workaround; however it doesn't work adequately with multiple inheritance, which can change the MRO (Method Resolution Order).

Try using my duper class: `duper(super()).setter = value`

```py
class duper:
    """Super wrapper which allows property setting & deletion.
    Super can't be subclassed with empty __init__ arguments.
    Works with multiple inheritance.
    
    References:
      https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2010-April/099672.html
      https://bugs.python.org/issue14965
      https://bugs.python.org/file37546/superprop.py
    
    Usage: duper(super())
    """

    def __init__(self, osuper):
        object.__setattr__(self, 'osuper', osuper)

    def _find(self, name):
        osuper = object.__getattribute__(self, 'osuper')
        if name != '__class__':
            mro = iter(osuper.__self_class__.__mro__)
            for cls in mro:
                if cls == osuper.__thisclass__:
                    break
            for cls in mro:
                if isinstance(cls, type):
                    try:
                        return object.__getattribute__(cls, name)
                    except AttributeError:
                        pass
        return None
    
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(object.__getattribute__(self, 'osuper'), name)

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        osuper = object.__getattribute__(self, 'osuper')
        desc = object.__getattribute__(self, '_find')(name)
        if hasattr(desc, '__set__'):
            return desc.__set__(osuper.__self__, value)
        return setattr(osuper, name, value)

    def __delattr__(self, name):
        osuper = object.__getattribute__(self, 'osuper')
        desc = object.__getattribute__(self, '_find')(name)
        if hasattr(desc, '__delete__'):
            return desc.__delete__(osuper.__self__)
        return delattr(osuper, name)
```

(full source https://gist.github.com/willrazen/bef3fcb26a83dffb6692e5e10d3e67ac)

Comment: What do you mean by "mro"?

Comment: @OmarL Method Resolution Order is the order in which base classes are searched for a member during lookup. (ref. Python docs)

Comment: To be clear `super(type(self), type(self))` is broken in subclassing cases, but `super(__class__, type(self))` works safely, with no infinite recursion risk, in Py3 (`__class__` is provided when a function defined in a class references `super` or `__class__` to assist in implementing no-arg `super` via a faked closure scope).