# Using super() in a property's setter method when using the @property decorator raises an AttributeError

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am a little confused by the behavior when attempting to overwrite a property in a subclass.

The first example sets up two classes, `Parent` and `Child`.  `Parent` inherits from `object`, while `Child` inherits from `Parent`.  The property `a` is defined using the property decorator.  When `child.a`'s setter method is called, an `AttributeError` is raised.

In the second example, by using the `property()` function rather than the decorator, everything works as would be expected.

Can anyone shed some light on why the behavior differs?  Also, yes, I know that the `__init__` definition in Child is not needed.

#### Example 1 - Using `@property`

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._a = 'a'
    @property
    def a(self):
        return self._a
    @a.setter
    def a(self, val):
        self._a = val

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Child, self).__init__()
    @property
    def a(self):
        return super(Child, self).a
    @a.setter
    def a(self, val):
        val += 'Child'
        super(Child, self).a = val

p = Parent()
c = Child()
print p.a, c.a
p.a = 'b'
c.a = 'b'
print p.a, c.a
```

#### Example 1 return - Raises an attribute error

```
a a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testsuper.py", line 26, in <module>
    c.a = 'b'
  File "testsuper.py", line 20, in a
    super(Child, self).a = val
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'a'
```

#### Example 2 - `Using property()`

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._a = 'a'
    def _get_a(self):
        return self._a
    def _set_a(self, val):
        self._a = val
    a = property(_get_a, _set_a)

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Child, self).__init__()
    def _get_a(self):
        return super(Child, self)._get_a()
    def _set_a(self, val):
        val = val+'Child'
        super(Child, self)._set_a(val)
    a = property(_get_a, _set_a)

p = Parent()
c = Child()
print p.a, c.a
p.a = 'b'
c.a = 'b'
print p.a, c.a
```

#### Example 2 return - Works correctly

```
a a
b bChild
```

Comment: My first advice is not to use the decorator form in this case. (I find it actually annoying but for read only properties)

Comment: Even so, kind of an odd issue.

Comment: I get a different error for Example 1 on line 12 `super(Child, self).a = val` -- `TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type`.

Comment: Thanks.  I somehow used the setter from `Child` as the setter in `Parent` when I copied and pasted.  Should be fixed now.

Comment: Even with your change I'm getting a different error. Now it's on line 20 `super(Child, self).a = val` -- `AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'a'`.

Comment: Ugh...sorry, apparently I really did a bad job putting this question together.  The error that you are getting now is the error that I am seeing as well.  I'm not sure how I copied and pasted the wrong error...  Edited again.  Thanks for looking at this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`super()` returns a proxy object, not a superclass, and it doesn't support the function `__set__()`.

And you can see more details here [Python super and setting parent class property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10810369/python-super-and-setting-parent-class-property) and here http://bugs.python.org/issue14965.