# @property decorator behavior with inheritance in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, decorator

I'm learning the python `@property` decorator. I am stuck and couldn't able to find the solution. I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35290540/understanding-property-decorator-and-inheritance) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13595607/using-super-in-a-propertys-setter-method-when-using-the-property-decorator-r) in SO, but my question is different.

Here, I have created a `Base` class in which I made the function `fun_name` as an attribute to this `Base` class using `@property` decorator. Everything works as expected.

I want to know about the behavior of this with inheritance.

For this, I have created another class `Derived` which is derived from the `Base` class. Here in the `Derived` class , I am trying to access the property attribute function `fun_name` using the `Derived` class member function `sample_fun` .

Accessing the `fun_name` attribute directly using the `Base` class object (`obj1`) works as expected. But I am confused with the behavior when I am calling the same using the `Derived` class member function `sample_fun` using the `obj2` object.

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
      
    @property
    def fun_name(self):
        print("Entered the getter fun_name")
        return "Getter-> Hello {}".format(self.name)

    @fun_name.setter
    def fun_name(self,str):
        self.name = str
        print("Setter-> Hello {}".format(self.name))

    def fun_name1(self):
        print("Hello from fun_name1 {}".format(self.name))

class Derived(Base):
    def sample_fun(self):
        print("Calling base call fun directly")
        Base.fun_name1(self)
        print("It works")
        print("Calling base attrib directly")
        
        Base.fun_name     #Here Why it is not entering  into the fun_name ?
        

        print("It prints here but not entering into the fun_name")
        
       
obj1 = Base("Joe")
obj1.fun_name
obj1.fun_name = "Jim"
obj1.fun_name

obj2 = Derived("RAJ")
obj2.sample_fun()
```

**Console output:**

```
Entered the getter fun_name
Setter-> Hello Jim
Entered the getter fun_name
Calling base call fun directly
Hello from fun_name1 RAJ
It works
Calling base attrib directly
It prints here but not entering into the fun_name
```

As you can see when I am directly accessing it using the `Base` class object (`obj1`) , it enters into the function.

But the same behavior is not happening with the `Derived` class member function. Exactly at the place `Base.fun_name` in the `sample_fun` method.

Am I missing some important concept here?

Comment: You might want to ``print(Base.fun_name)`` instead of just accessing it.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi: I tried that. Even then it was not showing.

Comment: It would have tipped you off though by showing `<Property fun_name>` instead of `Getter hello`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Paul Becotte already provide a good solution to the question I asked. I found one more way (anyway already existing) to access the same functionality which I need here. Because the `Derived` class is already derived from `Base` class. Hence all the properties of this `Base` class is available with `Derived` class. So my question was, how to access the property attribute function `fun_name` using the `Derived` class member function `sample_fun`.

My initial idea was to call like this:

```
Base.fun_name  #This was wrong and Paul already gave an explanation on this
```

@Paul's suggestion was:

```
Base("ANY NAME").fun_name  #This worked and explanation to this also he had given
```

Another solution of mine (calling with `self` since it is derived from `Base`):

```
self.fun_name #This solution also worked since the Derived class is derived from Base
```

Many thanks !

Comment: Your solution to use `self.fun_name` is much more natural than creating some new instance of `Base`. That "works" in the sense of not raising an exception, but it ignores the property that you can access on the `Derived` object.

Comment: Exactly @Blckknght

Comment: That's true, it does make much more sense, assuming it was the same instance you were trying to get the data from. :) Was trying to explain how it worked though, figured using `self.fun_name` would be less clear what is happening.

Comment: @PaulBecotte: I am using the same instance.

Answer (score 1):

`@property` adds an instance method that gets triggered on property access. Note the `self` argument. It adds a property object on the class. When you access an instance of that class, python will call the method and pass the class instance to it.

`Base.fun_name` is the actual property object on the class. If you did `Base().fun_name` it would work like you expect. If `Base.fun_name` DID get called, it would throw an exception because there's no `self` to get passed.

Comment: Ohh.. +1 for this.  Thanks you @Paul. It worked.