# Trying to subclass mechanize's Browser and create a login method

Tags: python, oop, mechanize

so that this way all I have to do is type

```
browser = MyBrowser()
browser.login()
```

to get my python scripts to log in in the future. Here's what I have so far:

```
import mechanize
class MyBrowser(mechanize.Browser, object):
    _username = 'username'
    _password = 'password'

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyBrowser, self).__init__()
        self.set_handle_robots(False)
        self.set_proxies({"http" : "http://proxy.me.com:80"})

    def login(self):
        self.open('http://login.mypage.com/')
        self.select_form(nr=0)
        self['name'] = self._username
        self['pass'] = self._password
        self.submit()
```

I had made a login function that worked fine using this same methodology. But now, when I call browser.login(), I get this:

```
self['name'] = self._username
TypeError: 'MyBrowser' object does not support item assignment
```

Why doesn't calling select_form behave the same way when it's part of a method like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self` is an object of the MyBrowser class.
What you have done with the `self['name']` and `self['pass']` is a try to assign values to the `self` object itself.

I assume you wanted to declare variables in the class, in order to do that you have to edit your code to:

```
self.name = self._username
self.pass = self._password
```

Edit:
Try this one:

```
super(MyBrowser, self).name = self._username
super(MyBrowser, self).password = self._password
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer! Unfortunately this doesn't work. What I'm trying to do is get it to assign those values to the form that should be a part of the `self` object after I assign the form to it using `self.select_form(nr=0)`

I based this on the model found here: [Download login-protected pages with Python using Mechanize and Splinter (Part 3)](http://ubuntuincident.wordpress.com/2011/11/08/download-login-protected-pages-with-python-using-mechanize-and-splinter-part-3/)

Comment: Read that thread for more information:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021464/python-how-to-call-a-property-of-the-base-class-if-this-property-is-being-overw

Comment: Thanks! I just realized what was actually causing the error with your original answer though:

`self.pass = self._password`

pass is a reserved word, and it won't let me use it as a field name, but that's what it is in the form! :( I'm looking for ways to escape reserved words... hmm

Answer (score 1):

I got it!!!

```
self.select_form(nr=0)
self.form['name'] = self._username
self.form['pass'] = self._password
self.submit()
```

Thanks so much Lior, I really appreciate your time on this and couldn't have gotten it without your help :)