# Why can't Python properties and property-setters be inherited?

Tags: python, properties, abc

My class hierarchy looks like:

```
- Foo_ABC      # abstract base class
  - Baz_ABC    # abstract base class
    - Baz1
    - Baz2
  - Bar
  ...
```

`Baz_ABC` defines an abstractproperty `thing`, but also implements the setter `@thing.setter` because the code is the same for both `Baz1` and `Baz2`. Yet in my tests I cannot set `thing`:

```
>>> b = baz1()
>>> b.thing = 42
AttributeError: "can't set attribute" on b.thing
```

Simply moving `@thing.setter` to the subclasses `Baz1` and `Baz2` resolves this. Why? Yes I know I can [call `super` from the subclasses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37663266/3765905). But I want to know why Python requires the class to define both the getter and setter.

Comment: What is the *exact* code to run to reproduce the observed `AttributeError`?