# Call the current class's version of a method in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

I have a two-class inheritance hierarchy:

```py
class TfIdfSimilarity(SimilarityModel):
    @property
    def corpus(self):
        return self.model[self._corpus]

    @property
    def model(self):
        return TfidfModel(self._corpus, dictionary=self._dict)


class LsiSimilarity(TfIdfSimilarity):
    @property
    def corpus(self):
        tfidf_corpus = super().corpus
        return self.model[tfidf_corpus]

    @property
    def model(self):
        tfidf_corpus = super().corpus
        return LsiModel(tfidf_corpus)
```

However, this is causing an infinite recursion error, because whenever I try to get the `LsiSimilarity#model`, it calls `TfIdfSimilarity#corpus`, which then tries to access the model, and thus calls `LsiSimilarity#model` again.

What I actually want is for `TfIdfSimilarity#corpus` to only ever call `TfIdfSimilarity#model`, and never consider the child class's version of it.

Is this possible in Python? (Python 3) If not, how can I better structure my inheritance hierarchy, while still providing the same API via the `corpus` and `model` functions (which are used by my main logic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [invoke descriptors directly](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#invoking-descriptors) by getting a reference to the descriptor from the class and then calling the `__get__` method of the descriptor:

```
TfIdfSimilarity.model.__get__(self)
```

If you find yourself doing this a lot, it may be a sign that you should be using regular methods instead of properties.

Comment: Note that while this works for `property`, this is due to the specific implementation of `property.__get__` (which returns `self` if no instance is provided) and is by no mean garanteed to be the case for all descriptors (ie in py2 
 `FunctionType.__get__` returns an unbound method, not the function itself).

Comment: After some searching, I now found a solution without a call to `__get__` :)

Answer (score 1):

You can always specify which method you want to call using instead of `self.method_xy` a call with `SpecificClass.method(self, other_arguments)`.

I first missed the implications of the property decorator and switched to the solution with calling `__get__` (`TfIdfSimilarity.model.__get__(self)`), but since it is a call to a private method I don't liked the solution.

Inspired by this [How to call a property of the base class if this property is being overwritten in the derived class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021464/how-to-call-a-property-of-the-base-class-if-this-property-is-being-overwritten-i), I found the method `fget`:

#### Minimal example

```py
class Test:
    def __init__(self, text):
        self._text = text

    @property
    def text(self):
        return self._text

class InheritTest(Test):

    @property
    def text(self):
        return "test" + self._text    


test = InheritTest("Test")
print(Test.text.fget(test))
# Test
print(test.text)
# testTest
```

Comment: Did you try this?  `TfIdfSimilarity.model` isn't a method, it's a [property](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property).  If you do this, you're going to be told that it's not callable.

Comment: Yeah you'd need to "deref" the property descriptor by calling `__get__(self)`

Comment: I wasn't aware of additional call needed for properties. Have now included the additional call. Thanks to Masklinn